# given a polynomial how can you derive its bezier representation

Tags: bezier-curve

I am developing an application that renders ECG rhythms that need to be animatable in response to user input. That part is not relevant to this site3, however I am starting with hand drawn rhythms, determining their polynomial representation and need to determine a bezier representation of those polynomials, which is the reason I am asking the question here. ( I can draw the rhythms using software like adobe illustrator, however the representation is not predictable and in order to animate them the bezier representation has to fit a certain format, so illustrator and the like are not an option, only drawing them by hand is).

So the question I need help with is, given a curve how can you derive the control points of its bezier representation? for example, if I wished to derive the bezier representation of a parabola:

$$F(x) = x^2, \:\:  \{-2 \leq x \geq 2\}$$

with a parameterization such as:

$$F(t) = (4t -2)^2, \:\: \{0 \leq t \geq 1\} $$

what is method of obtaining the bezier coefficients for $F(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a Bézier curve is $$P(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (1-t)^{n-k} t^k P_k = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} \binom{n-k}{j} (-t)^j t^k P_k $$
So if you have an expression for $P(t)$ in the form $$P(t) = \sum_{i=0}^n t^i A_i$$ you can equate coefficients of powers of $t$ to get simultaneous linear equations which you can solve for the $P_k$.

---

Your example is a quadratic, so $n = 2$ and $$\begin{eqnarray}
P(t) &=& \binom{2}{0}(1-t)^2 t^0 P_0 + \binom{2}{1}(1-t)^1 t^1 P_1 + \binom{2}{2}(1-t)^0 t^2 P_2 \\
&=& (1-2t+t^2) P_0 + (2t-2t^2) P_1 + t^2 P_2 \\
&=& t^2 (P_0 - 2 P_1 + P_2) + t(-2 P_0 + 2 P_1) + P_0 \\
\end{eqnarray}$$
If we equate coefficients with the general quadratic $P(t) = t^2 A_2 + t A_1 + A_0$ we get
$$\begin{eqnarray}
P_0& & &=& A_0 \\
-2P_0& + 2P_1& &=& A_1 \\
P_0& - 2P_1& + P_2 &=& A_2 \\
\end{eqnarray}$$
which we can solve by Gaussian elimination without pivoting to get
$$\begin{eqnarray}
P_0 &=& A_0 \\
P_1 &=& A_0 + \tfrac12 A_1 \\
P_2 &=& A_0 + A_1 + A_2 \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

This can now be applied separately in the $x$- and $y$-coordinates: $$\begin{eqnarray}
x(t) &=& 4t-2 & \implies & x_0 = -2, & x_1 = 0, & x_2 = 2 \\
y(t) &=& (4t-2)^2 & \implies & y_0 = 4, & y_1 = -4, & y_2 = 4 \\
\end{eqnarray}$$
So the Bézier control points are $(-2, 4), (0, -4), (2, 4)$.

Comment: And since this is for a graphic essentially and I don’t care about time, I have the freedom to pick any arbitrary number for T then?

Comment: If you pick a value of $t$ you collapse the polynomial to a point. It's not "time" but "independent variable".

Comment: i updated my question above, could you elaborate a bit more on your instruction? i included an example above and i believe you are stating i make linear equations from the coefficients for $F(t)$ , which in this case would be 16, -16, and 4, but how exactly i do that i dont know

Comment: im sorry if this sounds like a bad student question but i am actually needing this for an application i am developing that involves taking arbitrarily complex polynomials and generating a bezier representation of in a certain format and under certain (programming) constraints, so i have a need to 'draw' them by hand and this is a bit out of my depth

Comment: I've worked that example, and in fact all quadratic examples, and I hope you can see how to apply the same approach to higher degrees.

Comment: ok, yes i follow your example. another question, [mdn[(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#Path_commands) shows the different path commands for svg, which are bezier curves. you drawing second order polynomials with either the cubic or quadratic bezier curves. so, in the example above, would **A1** have two definitions for the two different control points, or how does that work?

Comment: If you're expressing a quadratic as a cubic then $A_3 =(0, 0)$

Comment: I'm going to open a separate question, but before I do let me make sure I have this right, performing the same technique for `n = 3` then $$ P_0 = A_0 \;\; P_1 = A_0 + A_1/3 \;\;P_2 = 3*A_0 + 2*A_1 + A_2 \;\; P_3 = 13*A_0 + 3*A_1 + 3*A_2 + A_3$$